# My Custom button need to add disable and enable functions

Tags: jquery

I have a custom button named ‘rename’. I need the button will always disabled. When I click in a checkbox, the button will enabled. If checkbox is checked, button should be enable.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="listcheck">
 <input type="checkbox" name="listcheck">
 <input type="checkbox" name="listcheck">


 <span class="down_btn" id="rename_fun"><a href="#">Rename</a></span>

    .down_btn a {
        background: url("../images/btn_down.png") no-repeat;
        color: #000000;
        display: block;
        height: 20px;
        padding-top: 4px;
        width: 114px;
    }
.down_btn a:hover
{
    width:114px;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    background:url(../images/btn_down_over.png) no-repeat;
    padding-top:4px;
}
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance
Bhavan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='listcheck']").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(".down_btn").click(function() {
            // I am enabled
            // something should happen here
        });
    } else {

        // unchecked, disable button
        $(".down_btn").unbind("click");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[name=listcheck]").click(function(){

   if(this.checked){
     $("#rename_fun").bind('click.customButton', function(){
        //Click logic here
     });
   }
   else{
     $("#rename_fun").unbind('click.customButton');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that you want the button to be enable "even if one item is selected" - I guess that's what is required

```
$('.listcheck').click(function() { 

$('.listcheck').each(function(){  //iterate over the list to ensure no others are selected

   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
      $('#down_button').attr('disabled',false); //if so enable and return
      return false;
   }
   else
      $('#down_button').attr('disabled',true)

   }

}
```